# How can I read an odd file type that uses multiple delimiters into R?

Tags: r, delimiter

My source file is from an older test machine that spits out "*.ctf" files. When I open the file  using readLines() I get a single long vector that has sections preceded by "[header_name]" and within the sections (in between headers) 4 columns are separated by a tab "\t".

Ideally I would like to separate each section into its own list/dataframe of 4 columns each.

Here is an example from the vector after it is read into R using readLines()
(note that I skipped from line 5 to 21)

```
vector
    [1] "[HEADER]" "Created by Sigma-1 ICON Version 4.5.3; Copyright 2005, GEOTAC"
    [3] "Project:\tACC#1210004 \tLoad Frame Name:\tLoad Frame" "Date:\t1/1/2002 \tTime:\t12:39:01 AM "                                      
    [5] "Boring:\tBoring2\tSample:\tSample7"
    
    ...
    
    [21] "" "[STEP 1]\t850\t0"                                                          
    [23] "Time\tExternal Load Cell\tDCDT\tPlaten Position" "1/1/2002 12:40:52 AM\t-2.31623424260761E-04 \t 3.45233241577262 \t 3150948 "
    [25] "1/1/2002 12:41:07 AM\t-3.22715023139608E-04 \t 3.45440429846349 \t 3157103 " "1/1/2002 12:41:22 AM\t-3.2964900303341E-04 \t 3.4553244755898 \t 3158611 "
```

Ideally, reading the file would produce multiple lists named by the [header] and delimited into 4 columns by "\t" with the first 4 columns being the column headers. For example, [STEP 1] looks like this in EXCEL, and something similar to this as a dataframe would be perfect.

[image: Snippet from Excel]

I'm hoping something like read.table can handle this using the tab delimiters, but it throws errors since there are multiple columns top of each other.

EDIT in response to comment:

```
    > dput(head(vector, 40))
c("[HEADER]", "Created by Sigma-1 ICON Version 4.5.3; Copyright 2005, GEOTAC", 
"Project:\tACC#1210004 \tLoad Frame Name:\tLoad Frame", "Date:\t1/1/2002 \tTime:\t12:39:01 AM ", 
"Boring:\tBoring2\tSample:\tSample7", "Specimen:\tSpecimen1\tDepth (ft):\t 21 ", 
"Diameter (inch):\t 2.5025 \tHeight (inch):\t 1.00825 ", "Comments:\tTare J 217.028 paper .311 .463  wet weight 379.024g", 
"", "[SENSORS]", "Name\tExternal Load Cell\tDCDT\tLoad Frame Encoder", 
"ID\t227396\tLP183\tN/A", "Module\tLoad Frame ADIO\tLoad Frame ADIO\tN/A", 
"Channel\t 1 \t 2 \tN/A", "Unit\tlbs\tinch\tinch", "Cal. Factor\t-796107.1205 \t 3.02704684 \t 3940000 ", 
"Excitation\t 9.98139953613281 \t 9.98139953613281 \tN/A", "Zero\t 3.38862647549831E-05 \t 3.10994816131097 \tN/A", 
"Min. Reading\t-1000 \t-0.05 \t0.0", "Max. Reading\t 2000 \t 3 \t 1.5 ", 
"", "[STEP 1]\t850\t0", "Time          \tExternal Load Cell\tDCDT\tPlaten Position", 
"1/1/2002 12:40:52 AM\t-2.31623424260761E-04 \t 3.45233241577262 \t 3150948 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:41:07 AM\t-3.22715023139608E-04 \t 3.45440429846349 \t 3157103 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:41:22 AM\t-3.2964900303341E-04 \t 3.4553244755898 \t 3158611 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:41:38 AM\t-3.35823094719672E-04 \t 3.45592288755324 \t 3159627 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:41:53 AM\t-3.34113346252707E-04 \t 3.45707221846715 \t 3160244 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:42:24 AM\t-3.25707082956796E-04 \t 3.45724794261514 \t 3160806 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:42:54 AM\t-3.34350811317563E-04 \t 3.45749134430662 \t 3161526 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:43:24 AM\t-3.32652936103841E-04 \t 3.4578036108669 \t 3161849 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:43:54 AM\t-3.31216272461461E-04 \t 3.45799833222009 \t 3162033 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:44:54 AM\t-3.2508967378817E-04 \t 3.45834978051607 \t 3162380 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:45:54 AM\t-3.28473550962372E-04 \t 3.45827497902064 \t 3162464 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:46:54 AM\t-3.32878527915454E-04 \t 3.4585171933868 \t 3162704 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:47:54 AM\t-3.23534277613362E-04 \t 3.45914291383269 \t 3161933 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:49:54 AM\t-3.38494576699304E-04 \t 3.45977932020651 \t 3162452 ", 
"1/1/2002 12:50:56 AM\t-3.31038173662819E-04 \t 3.45979950473702 \t 3159002 ", 
"", "[STEP 2]\t1700\t0")
```

Comment: use the function `dput(head(vector, 40))` where vector is your vector, and copy and paste the values into the question, dummify the data if need be.

Comment: hello_friend - I edited the question. I left most of the raw data in to show how convoluted it is. If it's helpful, the section headings will always be the same [HEADER], [SENSORS], and then [STEP 1], [STEP 2] ... [STEP 12].

Comment: Can you provide data for atleast two steps so as to confirm my answer below works in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data follows the pattern [STEP1][COLUMNNAMES][DATA][STEP2][COLUMNNAMES][DATA].... I think this will work.

```
start <- grep('^Time', vector)
end <- grep('\\[STEP', vector)[-1] - 2
result <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) 
             read.csv(text = paste0(vector[x:y], collapse = '\n'), sep = '\t'), 
             start, end))
result
```

The logic here is that we assume that the first column name is `'Time'` and the data starts from there until the next STEP is found.

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar problem from social media monitoring outputs all the time.
Here I assume that `rl_text` is the vector of lines that you pasted in your dput.
I load the `tidyverse` and `splitstackshape` packages.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

df_raw <- 
  rl_text %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    rowid_to_column(var = "line_id") %>% 
    splitstackshape::cSplit("value", sep = "\t", direction = "wide") %>% 
    mutate_if(.predicate = is.factor, as.character) %>% 
    mutate(is_header = grepl("^\\[.*\\]$", value_1), ## Here I check if the first column has a header, identified as a string that begins and ends in straight brackets []
           header = ifelse(is_header == TRUE, value_1, NA)) %>% 
    fill(header)

ls_headers <- unique(df_raw$header)

unnest_dfs <- function(headers, df = df_raw) {
  ## Function to get a df out of those rows under a common header.
  df_filtered <- filter(df, header == headers) %>% select(-c(line_id, is_header, header))
  df_filtered
}

list_with.dfs <- map(ls_headers, unnest_dfs)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  value_1                                                    value_2                                          value_3         value_4   
  <chr>                                                      <chr>                                            <chr>           <chr>     
1 [HEADER]                                                   NA                                               NA              NA        
2 Created by Sigma-1 ICON Version 4.5.3; Copyright 2005, GE~ NA                                               NA              NA        
3 Project:                                                   ACC#1210004                                      Load Frame Nam~ Load Frame
...        
[[2]]
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   value_1      value_2              value_3          value_4           
   <chr>        <chr>                <chr>            <chr>             
 1 [SENSORS]    NA                   NA               NA                
 2 Name         External Load Cell   DCDT             Load Frame Encoder
 3 ID           227396               LP183            N/A               
 ...
[[3]]
# A tibble: 18 x 4
   value_1              value_2               value_3          value_4        
   <chr>                <chr>                 <chr>            <chr>          
 1 [STEP 1]             850                   0                NA             
 2 Time                 External Load Cell    DCDT             Platen Position
 3 1/1/2002 12:40:52 AM -2.31623424260761E-04 3.45233241577262 3150948        
 ...           
[[4]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  value_1  value_2 value_3 value_4
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 [STEP 2] 1700    0       NA
```